# Laravel Multiple Middleware In One Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I had 2 user types in my laravel app and have now added a third.
Im trying to add the 3rd user type's middleware into an existing function at the top of my controller.

Below was my code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin')
        ->except('route', 'route2');
}
```

Now I have added another middleware to this but that causes a 404 page:

```
$this->middleware(['admin', 'viewer'])
        ->except('route', 'route2');
```

I also tried this but it said it needed to be an array so this doesn't work:

```
$this->middleware(['admin', 'viewer'])
        ->except('route', 'route2');
```

The issues isn't with the middleware itself I don't think because if I swap the middleware name when Im just passing one it works like and shows the expected view, not a 404:

```
$this->middleware('viewer')
        ->except('route', 'route2');
```

Thanks!

Comment: what are these middleware doing? please provide them

Comment: @lagbox ahh I see the error now. The middleware class aborts to a 404 if the user type isn't correct. So when I add 2 middleware classes and both abort it causes the 404.

Comment: glad you solved your problem ...  you can probably close this as it doesn't seem it will be useful to other users since the problem doesn't have to do with what is in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$this->middleware(['admin', 'viewer'])
        ->except(['route', 'route2']);
```

and which laravel version are you using? Also you can check this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

Comment: `except` will use `func_get_args` to get all the arguments if the first argument is not an array, so this is the same thing ... https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4bde31b24bf01b4d4a35ad31fafd8e4ca203b0f2/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerMiddlewareOptions.php#L46